# jquery iterate elements by class name to get value, problem with divs

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm able to get all elements with the same class name with... `convInputs=$('body').find('.convertUnits')`

I iterate it like this to get the values...

```
$.each(convInputs, function(index, item){
    alert(item.value);
});
```

But when it's a div it gives me undefined... I tried `item.text` which doesn't work either.

How do I get the value of the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `textContent`:

```js
$.each($('.test'), function(index, item){
   console.log(item.value + ' using value.');
   console.log(item.text + ' using text.');
   console.log(item.textContent + ' using textContent.');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">ABC</div>
```